# Optimize JSON denormalization using JQ - "cartesian product" from 1:N

Tags: json, performance, jq, wal, json-query

I have a JSON database change log, output of `wal2json`. It looks like this:

```
{"xid":1190,"timestamp":"2018-07-19 17:18:02.905354+02","change":[
    {"kind":"update","table":"mytable2","columnnames":["id","name","age"],"columnvalues":[401,"Update AA",20],"oldkeys":{"keynames":["id"],"keyvalues":[401]}},
    {"kind":"update","table":"mytable2","columnnames":["id","name","age"],"columnvalues":[401,"Update BB",20],"oldkeys":{"keynames":["id"],"keyvalues":[401]}}]}
 ...
```

Each top level entry (`xid`) is a transaction, each item in `change` is, well, a change. One row may change multiple times.

To import to an OLAP system with limited feature set,  I need to have the order explicitly stated. So I need to add a `sn` for each change in a transaction.
Also, each change must be a top level entry - the OLAP can't iterate sub-items within one entry.

```
{"xid":1190, "sn":1, "kind":"update", "data":{"id":401,"name":"Update AA","age":20} }
{"xid":1190, "sn":2, "kind":"update", "data":{"id":401,"name":"Update BB","age":20} }
{"xid":1191, "sn":1, "kind":"insert", "data":{"id":625,"name":"Inserted","age":20} }
{"xid":1191, "sn":2, "kind":"delete", "data":{"id":625} }
```

(The reason is that the OLAP has limited ability to transform the data during import, and also doesn't have the order as a parameter.)

So, I do this using `jq`:

```
function transformJsonDataStructure {
    ## First let's reformat it to XML, then transform using XPATH, then back to JSON.

    ## Example input:
    # {"xid":1074,"timestamp":"2018-07-18 17:49:54.719475+02","change":[
    #   {"kind":"update","table":"mytable2","columnnames":["id","name","age"],"columnvalues":[401,"Update AA",20],"oldkeys":{"keynames":["id"],"keyvalues":[401]}},
    #   {"kind":"update","table":"mytable2","columnnames":["id","name","age"],"columnvalues":[401,"Update BB",20],"oldkeys":{"keynames":["id"],"keyvalues":[401]}}]}
    cat "$1" | while read -r LINE ; do
        XID=`echo "$LINE" | jq -c '.xid'`;
        export SN=0;
        #serr "{xid: $XID, changes: $CHANGES}";
        echo "$LINE" | jq -c '.change[]' | while read -r CHANGE ; do
            SN=$((SN+=1))
            KIND=`echo "$CHANGE" | jq -c --raw-output .kind`;
            TABLE=`echo "$CHANGE" | jq -c --raw-output .table`;
            DEST_FILE="$TARGET_PATH-$TABLE.json";
            case "$KIND" in
                update|insert)
                    MAP=$(convertTwoArraysToMap "$(echo "$CHANGE" | jq -c ".columnnames")" "$(echo "$CHANGE" | jq -c ".columnvalues")") ;;
                delete)
                    MAP=$(convertTwoArraysToMap "$(echo "$CHANGE" | jq -c ".oldkeys.keynames")" "$(echo "$CHANGE" | jq -c ".oldkeys.keyvalues")") ;;
            esac
            #echo "{\"xid\":$XID, \"table\":\"$TABLE\", \"kind\":\"$KIND\", \"data\":$MAP }" >> "$DEST_FILE"; ;;
            echo "{\"xid\":$XID, \"sn\":$SN, \"kind\":\"$KIND\", \"data\":$MAP }" | tee --append "$DEST_FILE";
        done;
    done;

    return;
}
```

The problem is the performance. I am calling `jq` few times per entry. This is quite slow, around 1000x times slower than without the transformation.

**How can perform the transformation above using just one pass?** (`jq` is not a must, other tool can be used too, but should be in CentOS packages. I want to avoid coding an extra tool for that.

From `man jq` it seems that it could be capable of processing the whole file (JSON entry per row) in one go. I could do it in XSLT but I can't wrap my head around `jq`. Especially the iteration of the `change` array and combining `columnnames` and `columnvalues` to a map.

- For the iteration, I think `map` or `map_values` could be used.
- For the 2 arrays to map, I see the `from_entries` and `with_entries` functions, but can't get it work.

Any `jq` master around to advise?

Answer (score 0):

The following helper function converts the incoming array into an object using `headers` as the keys:

```
def objectify(headers):
  [headers, .] | transpose | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add;
```

The trick now is to use `range(0;length)` to generate `.sn`:

```
  {xid} +
  (.change
   | range(0;length) as $i
   | .[$i]
   | .columnnames as $header
   | {sn: ($i + 1),
      kind,
      data: (.columnvalues|objectify($header)) } )
```

### Output

For the given log entry, the output would be:

```
{"xid":1190,"sn":1,"kind":"update","data":{"id":401,"name":"Update AA","age":20}}
{"xid":1190,"sn":2,"kind":"update","data":{"id":401,"name":"Update BB","age":20}}
```

### Moral

If a solution looks too complicated, it probably is.

Comment: That looks promising, thanks! I will try in the morning.